# How do i rename image files in a directory prefixed with a certain word

Tags: php, arrays

Im working on a shopping cart solution for my client. The shopping cart is smart enough to associate file names with product id's so what i have to do is rename each image file name to associate it with a product id. (ie. product_id1 and product_id1.jpg)

```
$filename;

  function renamer(){
foreach(glob('./my_images/*.*') as $filename){

    for($i =0; $i<10;$i++ ){
      rename($filename, "/my_images/product_id".$i.".jpg");
    }  

}

}




renamer();
```

For some reason the files are not being renamed. I get an error message:

The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

Comment: Why is there a single quote inside the new filename?

Comment: is the `'` in `"'/my_images/...` a typo?

Comment: The file name have spaces in them.. would this be cause an issue? ex. 202181 (1).jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rename($filename, "/my_images/product_id".$i.".jpg");
```

Will attempt to move the files to `/my_images/product_id`. Note that this is in the root directory. If this is intended make sure that `/my_images` exists. Otherwise try:

```
rename($filename, "my_images/product_id".$i.".jpg");
```

Which will add the files to the `my_images` folder in the current directory. Again, make sure this exists.